# How to set the terminal title to show the current running command while it's running and to show it in brackets once it's finished?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

[From a different post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076127/bash-update-terminal-title-by-running-a-second-command/7110386#7110386) I already know what to put in my `.bashrc` to set the current executing command as the terminal title:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033]2;$(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g")\007"' DEBUG
```

I would like to adjust this in a way that if there's no command currently running, the title would be a modified version of the last command, for example the whole command in square brackets (like so: `[find . -maxdepth 1 -type f]`).

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can (ab)use PS1 by putting the same escape sequence in so that every time the prompt is printed, the title gets updated.

```
export PS1="\033]2;[\$(history 1 | sed 's/^[ ]*[0-9]*[ ]*//g')]\007$PS1"
```

The final PS1 just keeps your old prompt for the actual command line.

I don't actually use this, but it should work.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you but would you know how to leave the title intact while there was no command executed in the current tab yet? I tried many ways to set this up but all failed. Is it possible to temporarily set the PS1 as `export PS1="\033]2;Terminal\007$PS1"` before there are any commands run?

Comment: Good point.  The problem is that history returns a value from previous shells if it has to.  You could try pointing the history file to a per-instance file (use the process id $$ in the HISTFILE setting) and then use a small script to check if that file exists.  I'm sure it can be made to work but you will lose your cross-shell history.

Comment: For the timing being I solved it by putting `set -o history` followed by `# Terminal` at the end of my `.bashrc` ([reference](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5363/how-to-start-a-terminal-with-certain-text-already-input-on-the-command-line/5383#5383)). I'll see if something will force me to break from my laziness.

Answer (score 2):

Easy and quick way to do this on the fly:

1. Install the program **xtitle** onto your PC by running this command from your terminal window:  `sudo apt-get install xtitle` .

   - Enter your super user password when prompted.
2. Type **xtitle** ***YOUR_DESIRED_TITLE*** and hit **ENTER/RETURN**, e.g. `xtitle Tomcat` will set the title to **Tomcat**. Repeat that command each time you want a new title.

   - **NB:** This was tested on **Ubuntu 14.04** only.

Comment: You can even reduce the typing time by writing an alias for the command (step 2 ) in your `.bashrc` file.

Comment: how do i get xtitle on centos 8? 'sudo yum install xtitle' yields no results